# How to restore PostgreSQL database to initial state as it was after fresh install

Tags: postgresql, dspace

I am using PostgreSQL as a database for DSpace project. I am inserted some records in tables now i want a script with the help of which the database become empty only it contains the data in that table which is automatically inserted during fresh install.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[dspace]/bin/dspace database clean
[dspace]/bin/dspace database migrate
```

Swap in your actual DSpace install directory for [dspace].

According to [the official DSpace documentation](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/Database+Utilities):

> running "dspace database clean" followed by "dspace database migrate" will return your database to a fresh install state

Answer (score 0):

Just execute the following commands in your SSH terminal:

```
[dspace]/bin/dspace database clean
[dspace]/bin/dspace database migrate
```

***[dspace]*** is installation path of Dspace (e.g. /root/Dspace/installed/5.3) which is defined in the configuration file: ***dspace.cfg***
If you want to return your database to a ***fresh install*** state, just run the following command instead of the second one above:

```
[dspace]/bin/dspace database migrate ignored
```